# How do I upload a default picture if no picture is uplaoded by user using paperclip gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below is my code:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true

  has_attached_file :avatar,
                       :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
                       :default_url => ":style/missing.jpg" 
    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/


end
```

Also, my image is stored in app/assets/images/medium as missing.jpg and in app/assets/images/thumbs as missing.jpg. Right now the error that I get is that it simply displays the word missing and no picture.

Below is the code to display the picture in my view file.

```
<div class="profile-image">
    <%= image_tag @user.profile.avatar.url %>       
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure `:style/missing.jpg` is the correct path not `/assets/images/medium/missing.jpg`?

Comment: Hi, that doesn't work as well and gives same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
:default_url => "/images/:style/missing.jpg"
```

Source: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/README.md#models

Comment: Hi, that doesn't work and gives same error

Comment: Also, try changing your images directory to `thumb` instead of `thumbs` or change your style name for the size to `thumbs` (:styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumbs => "100x100"}). It looks like you're telling paperclip to look in `thumb/`, but you have the directory name as `thumbs`.